# Simple class failing nosetests3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

I'm learning python and I'm having some trouble with some simple unit tests I'm trying to run. I'm using `nosetests` to run some manually written tests, and I've got my github repository set up with Travis Continuous Integration for a bit of CI practice. I noticed that it was failing all builds for python 3.x, but passing anything for 2.x.

First, here are my two files.

fib.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#fib.py

import sys

def fib(n):
    if (n == 0):
        return 0
    if (n == 1):
        return 1    
    return fib(n -1) + fib(n - 2)        

def main():
   if (len(sys.argv) == 2):    
       print(fib(sys.argv[1]))   
   else:
       print("Usage: ", sys.argv[0], " [number]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

test_fib.py

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#testfib.py

import unittest
from fib import fib

class TestFib(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fib_0(self):
        self.assertEqual(fib(0), 0)

    def test_fib_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(fib(1), 1)

    def test_fib_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(fib(2), 1)

    def test_fib_range(self):
        for x in range(2,13):
            self.assertEqual(fib(x), fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
       unittest.main()
```

running  `python test_fib.py` :

```
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.018s

OK
```

running `nosetests`

```
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.053s

OK
pi@kepler:~/dev/Projects/Numbers/fib$
```

However, when I deploy to Travis CI and it runs `nosetests` with python3.x, or I run `nosetests3` on my machine, I see this:

```
EEEE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_fib_0 (fib.test_fib.TestFib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/dev/Projects/Numbers/fib/test_fib.py", line 9, in test_fib_0
    self.assertEqual(fib(0), 0)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_fib_1 (fib.test_fib.TestFib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/dev/Projects/Numbers/fib/test_fib.py", line 12, in test_fib_1
    self.assertEqual(fib(1), 1)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_fib_2 (fib.test_fib.TestFib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/dev/Projects/Numbers/fib/test_fib.py", line 15, in test_fib_2
    self.assertEqual(fib(2), 1)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

======================================================================
ERROR: test_fib_range (fib.test_fib.TestFib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/dev/Projects/Numbers/fib/test_fib.py", line 19, in test_fib_range
    self.assertEqual(fib(x), fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.034s

FAILED (errors=4)
```

I'm pretty new to python, so I'm not sure if my problem is with my code or with how I'm using nose. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Here are the versions of everything I'm running:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
$ python3 -V
Python 3.2.3
$ nosetests -V
nosetests version 1.3.0
$ nosetests3 -V
nosetests3 version 1.1.2
$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Are fib.py and test_fib.py in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, along with an empty \_\_init\_\_.py that nosetests apparently doesn't work correctly without.

Comment: If you have another fib package installed on py3, you might need `from .fib import fib` instead.

Comment: @sjotterman: was my answer of any help?

Comment: @ErikAllik I'm sorry, I've been away from home and unable to try your solution; I promise I'll let you know either way as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have some old files laying around, such as a `fib/fib.pyc` or something under `__pycache__` perhaps, because for me, everything works correctly under Python 3.3.2 with nosetests as well as without:

```
(python3.3.2)~/code/python/stackoverflow$ nosetests test_fib.py 
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

for example, run `python` (or `ipython`) in that directory and execute:

```
>>> from fib import fib
>>> fib
???
```

and see what it reports: if `fib` is reported to be a `<function ...>`, everything should be correct; if `<module ...>`, you have to investigate why it is so. For example, this is what I get:

```
>>> from fib import fib
>>> fib
<function fib at 0x10cb7d9e0>
```

You can also try adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` and see how Python 2.x behaves then; if the same problem starts occurring, it's an indication that you have a top-level package `fib` somewhere which Python 3.x imports by default but in Python 2.x gets overrided with the sibling package (i.e. a package in the same folder as `test_fib`), which is changed to Python 3.x behavior with the `__future__` import. For more information about future imports, see [Future statement definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html); about `absolute_import`, see [PEP 328 -- Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: `from __future__ import absolute_import` and changing my function call from `fib(0)` to `fib.fib(0)` fixed everything. Thank you!